# Facebook like button for Article Page & Like Button for your Facebook Page not displaying correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, sharing

I have a facebook like button on my Full Article page, but I would also like a facebook like button somewhere in the header where it gives the ability to like our 
"Facebook Page" and have nothing do do with an article on our website, by liking the actual post and sharing it.

I use sharethis for the like button for the article page along with all of our sharing, but i also have a separate area that is just a like button for users to like our "facebook page".

For some reason when the page loads. Sometimes none of the like buttons show up, or sometimes only one shows up, and the other is not there.

Any input or suggestions would be very appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Write the facebook page url get the code then paste it on your website

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple different Like buttons on your page that Like different URLs (such as your Article Page and your Home Page.)

To do that, simply specify different href parameters in your different Like buttons.  Here is an iframe example:

```
<iframe
  src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourpageurl.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;"
  allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

The href parameter of your Like button is what specifies which page the Like action is tied to, and it can be different from the page you are currently on.

We can't easily help you figure out why your buttons don't show up unless you post some code.

Comment: _“You can not implement a Like Button within your web page that is used to Like your Facebook Fan Page.”_ – sorry, but what gives you that idea? We are using this on multiple websites of ours, and it’s working perfectly.

Comment: My apologies!  I stand corrected.  I had thought that creating a button to Like the Fan Page URL wouldn't increment the Fan Page Likes, but you're right, it works perfectly.